# Control order of execution of 2 drools file in same package

Tags: drools, rules

I have 2 drools file in the same package com.sample.order.rules
orders.drl and order-summary.drl. I want to process all the orders in orders.drl and then from the results of order.drl processing, create an order summary using order-summary.drl. I currently control the order of execution by setting all the saliences in order-summary.drl to -1. Is it possible to solve this problem any other way? The problem is the number of rules is increasing and adding salience to every rule in order-summary.drl just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to control the execution order of groups of rules with the attribute `ruleflow-group`, see examples from the [docs](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#decision-examples-conway-ref_drools-examples).  In general, the approach is:

1. Tag your related rules with a `ruleflow-group` attribute.
2. Create a BPMN Flow (a Business Process)
3. Associate each of your `ruleflow-group`s with a Business Process Task
4. Trigger your rules under a jBPM Process

This allows you to (optionally) only trigger your Summary steps when some conditions in the previous Orders step have been satisfied. I would suggest looking at the Mortgage_Process example provided by the Drools Business Central Showcase [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/drools-workbench-showcase).  To set up the KIE Execution Server API to test your rules and processes iteratively, see the docker-compose set up [here](https://github.com/danial-k/docker-compose-intro/tree/master/drools-workbench-kie-server).

**Step 1**

```
rule "order rule 1"
  ruleflow-group "orders"
when
  Order ( value > 10 )
then
  insert ( new Shipment () );
end
```

```
rule "summary rule 1"
  ruleflow-group "summary"
when
  Shipment ()
then
  // do stuff
end
```

**Step 2**
[image]